# How do I terminate an un-bootable EBS-backed instance without deleting the volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have some instances, which are backed by a bad image. They do not boot. They are backed by a *good* volume, which is in use by another important instance. I have them stopped, but I can't terminate them without EC2 wanting to delete the volume.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html

Says that I need to change the DeleteOnTermination attribute, but I can't access that unless the instance is running.

I have now detached the volume, but I'm wondering if the volume will be destroyed if I delete the instance at this point.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where does it say you can't modify the `DeleteOnTermination` attribute unless the instance is running? Is the instance stopped? Why can't you just detach the EBS volume? Why can't you just take an EBS snapshot of the volume and then create a new stand-alone volume from the snapshot?

Comment: "You can change value of the DeleteOnTermination attribute for a volume when you launch the instance or while the instance is running." from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#preserving-volumes-on-termination#preserving-volumes-on-termination

The instance is stopped currently. I did detach the EBS volume, but it still warns me when I try to terminate that it will delete the volume.

Comment: The deletion of the volume would still affect my other running instance, which is an important part of production. I can take it offline after snapshotting its volume, but what is concerning is that I created these un-bootable instance by trying to boot snapshots of this volume in the first place @MarkB

Comment: "The deletion of the volume would still affect my other running instance," That's not possible. An EBS volume can not be attached to more than one instance at a time. If you took a snapshot of a bootable volume, and the volume you created from the snapshot won't boot then there is some other issue at play here. Perhaps you selected the wrong virtualization type when you created the new instance.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, that worked. I was too concerned to try deleting without being sure.